# How to add an out fault interceptor in jboss-webservices.xml?

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, cxf, wildfly

As far as I know, we can add "in" interceptors and "out" interceptors in jboss-webservices.xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webservices
  xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  version="1.2"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <property>
    <name>cxf.interceptors.in</name>
    <value>org.jboss.test.ws.jaxws.cxf.interceptors.BusInterceptor</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>cxf.interceptors.out</name>
    <value>org.jboss.test.ws.jaxws.cxf.interceptors.BusCounterInterceptor</value>
  </property>
</webservices>
```

But how to add an out fault interceptor?

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't use standard JAX-WS [javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/Handler.html)s instead?